# Fortran explicit shape vs allocated: When specifically does loss in access performance emerge?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have heard that working with assumed/explicit shape arrays is more efficient than allocatable arrays. But if I pass an allocated array to a subroutine that expects an explicit shape array, will I recover performance?

E.g. Consider the following two toy examples. Will both be equally efficient

Example 1:

```
program myprog
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: n = 1 000 000
    real, allocatable  :: x(:)

    allocate(x(n))

    call mysub(x,n)

contains

subroutine mysub(x,n)

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real, intent(inout) :: x(n)

!   Work with x

end subroutine

end program
```

Example 2:

```
program myprog
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: n = 1 000 000
    real :: x(n)

    call mysub(x,n)

contains

subroutine mysub(x,n)

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real, intent(inout) :: x(n)

!   Work with x

end subroutine

end program
```

Comment: There are no assumed shape arrays in the example source.

Comment: What exactly have you heard? Have you some citation? Your formulation is pretty unclear.

Comment: Example 1 would need to say ALLOCATABLE in the subroutine, and there is time required to allocate the array. If one is allocating and deallocating then that sucks up time. You may want to try a few ways and see what the time required is. I can tell you that how you so "work with X" is what is important for elapsed time.